# how to find a cell value where cell number depend on another cell value in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to store the value of Column B Cell B20 in Column F cell -- .
Column F cell will collect the 20 value from a formula in Column E cell E2.

So in Column F i want use a formula like :  B(E2). this formula will collect the value from B20 to the F column cell.

I am working with multiple sheets with more than thousand data.

It would be a great help.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula in column F

`=INDEX(B:B,E2)`